# Error loading heatmap layer using cartodb.js

Tags: carto, heat-map, carto-js

I'm trying to load a **heatmap** layer using cartodb.js, but it is failing whether I use createVis or the manual way.

Using createVis:

```
cartodb.createVis('mapDIV', 'https://PATH/viz.json');
```

Building a Leaflet map and then adding it:

```
var layerUrl = 'https://PATH/viz.json';
var cartoDB_lyr = cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
cartoDB_lyr.addTo(map);
```

Either way I am getting the following error message:

[image]

I am not sure how to debug this.

If I disable torque in CartoDB (i.e. visualizing the dataset as **simple**), then the dataset displays without a problem, so it must be specifically related to the heatmap:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heatmaps were added in a [more recent version of CartoDB.js](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/NEWS) than 3.11, the library that you're using. Upgrading to the most recent, 3.14, should fix your problem.

The library and associated CSS file follow the following format:
    http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.14/cartodb.js
    http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.14/themes/css/cartodb.css

Where the version number is explicit.

Comment: That did it! The tutorials I am using are still using version 3.11. Glad I asked! 

However, if I animate the heatmap I am still getting an error. Are animations perhaps not supported? Here are the errors:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: a.slider is not a function   ---- and ----   
Uncaught TypeError: this.$(...).slider is not a function

Comment: Hmmm, not sure the cause of that. Animations are supported. Are you doing anything programmatically to access the slider?

Comment: btw, what tutorial were you working from? i just did a pull request to updated all http://academy.cartodb.com lessons with the newest library.

Comment: Yep, it was the Academy one: http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up/lesson-1.html On that page it refers to <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>, which is not 3.14.

Comment: Updated! Thanks for finding it, and sorry it caused you some problems!